# R: combine vector elements with same names in list into list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of about 100,000 vectors, all with the same length of about 1,400 numbers. Some vectors have the same names (always by group of 5). I need to convert this list of vectors into a list of data frames combining the vectors having the same names by column. For now I use:

```
my_list %<>% split(names(.)) %>% map(bind_cols)
```

which works great but is very slow. It takes about 1s to process two groups so almost 3 hours in total which seems very slow for such a task. Would there be any other faster method to try for this?

Here is an example:

```
my_list <- list(
  v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  v2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  v2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  v2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  v3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  v3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  v3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
)
my_list %>% split(names(.)) %>% map(bind_cols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, we can `cbind` all of them at once to a single dataset and then `split`

```
split.default(as.data.frame(my_list), names(my_list))
```

Comment: Much faster indeed! Now it's less than 1 min! thanks

Comment: @Marc Thanks, I guess `setDT` from `data.table` could be faster `library(data.table);split.default(setDT(my_list), names(my_list))`